# Certain Xubuntu graphics persist on Ubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, lightdm, notification

I recently installed the Xubuntu desktop environment on my Ubuntu machine. It's nice, but I switched back to Ubuntu as by default desktop environment. But when I change the volume or brightness, the HUD icons are still from the XUbuntu theme. Also, when I shutdown, the splash screen says Xubuntu.

I'm quite sure that I am in fact running Ubuntu:

```
$ echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
ubuntu
```

and in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

```
user-session=ubuntu
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install these packages and their dependencies:

```
notify-osd
notify-osd-icons
```

Also purge this package:

```
xfce4-notifyd
```

Finally, you should reconfigure `plymouth`, e.g. by installing and using `galternatives` and update the `initramfs` with the `update-initramfs` command.

After a reboot, you should be back to normal.